# How to calculate the center of the bounding box?

Tags: python, api, geolocation, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

Im trying to calculate the center of the bounding box with these given points

```
(50.607041876988994, -1.3187316344406208, 52.40735812301099, 1.5737316344406207)
```

This is the code i done in python

```
def center_geolocation(geolocations):
    """
    Provide a relatively accurate center lat, lon returned as a list pair, given
    a list of list pairs.
    ex: in: geolocations = ((lat1,lon1), (lat2,lon2),)
        out: (center_lat, center_lon)
    """
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

    for lat, lon in geolocations:
        lat = float(lat)
        lon = float(lon)
        x += cos(lat) * cos(lon)
        y += cos(lat) * sin(lon)
        z += sin(lat)

    x = float(x / len(geolocations))
    y = float(y / len(geolocations))
    z = float(z / len(geolocations))

    return (atan2(y, x), atan2(z, sqrt(x * x + y * y)))
```

However i keep on getting this error

```
line 64, in center_geolocation
    for lat, lon in geolocations:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Can someone explain what im doing wrong or can someone correct the error i may have done,

thank you :)

Comment: What are you passing as argument to the function?

Comment: Im trying to pass these coordinates of the bounding box i calculated                          (50.607041876988994, -1.3187316344406208, 52.40735812301099, 1.5737316344406207)

Answer (score 2):

```
from math import *

def center_geolocation(geolocations):
    """
    Provide a relatively accurate center lat, lon returned as a list pair, given
    a list of list pairs.
    ex: in: geolocations = ((lat1,lon1), (lat2,lon2),)
        out: (center_lat, center_lon)
"""
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

for lat, lon in geolocations:
    lat = float(lat)
    lon = float(lon)
    x += cos(lat) * cos(lon)
    y += cos(lat) * sin(lon)
    z += sin(lat)

x = float(x / len(geolocations))
y = float(y / len(geolocations))
z = float(z / len(geolocations))

return (atan2(y, x), atan2(z, sqrt(x * x + y * y)))


center_geolocation( 
 ((50.607041876988994, -1.3187316344406208),   
  (52.40735812301099, 1.5737316344406207)))
```

There is not float error in the example you have given .... I do not like the output - but that was not the question.

Comment: One problem , it prints out (-1.4093883217883079, 0.6741482698408712) where it should print 51.51608899635712, 0.09891956707558282 , you know where i might have gone wrong?

Comment: This solution seems to do all the math on degrees, where I believe they should be converted to radians first, and back to degrees at the end, ie `lat = float(lat) * pi / 180` at the beginning (same for lon) and `atan2(y, x) * 180 / pi` (same for lon).

Comment: Also, I believe the output is (center_lon, center_lat), not as described.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `shapely` library:

```
from shapely.geometry import box

bounds = (-1.3187316344406208, 50.607041876988994, 1.5737316344406207, 52.40735812301099)
polygon = box(*bounds)

print(polygon.centroid.x, polygon.centroid.y)
```

`bounds` is defined as (South-West longitude, South-West latitude, North-East longitude, North-East latitude).